# Qt Creator не изменяется свойства CheckBox

Tags: c++, qt

Имею вот такой код.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

int connection;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void internet_test(){
    if (system("ping -c1 -s1 www.google.com")){
            connection = 0;
            std::cout<<"\nNot connnected to the internet\n\n" << std::endl;
    }
    else{

           connection = 1;
           std::cout<<"\nConnected to the internet\n\n" << std::endl;

    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    internet_test();
    if (connection == 1){
        QPushButton*checkBox=dynamic_cast<QPushButton*>(QObject::sender());
        checkBox->setChecked(true);
    }

}
```

Чек бокс и кнопка, нарисованы в графическом редакторе.
Если есть соединение с интернетом, то checkBox, должен отметится как "checked". Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: а он у вас вообще есть??? этот checkBox???

Comment: @Akuma925 да, нарисован в графическом редакторе.

Comment: ну вы кнему не обращаетесь.

Comment: ну если кратко то вам нужно указть ui->cb->setCheckrd(true); в той првоерке и все.

Comment: @Akuma925 благодарю )

Comment: @Akuma925 не могли бы еще помочь, как запихать эту проверку и отметку "checked", через QObject::connect(pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(internet_test()));

Comment: это не по теме.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

int internet_test(){
     int connection;
    if (system("ping -c1 -s1 www.google.com")){
          connection = 0;
          std::cout<<"\nNot connnected to the internet\n\n" << std::endl;
          return 0;
    }
    else{

         connection = 1;
         std::cout<<"\nConnected to the internet\n\n" << std::endl;
         return 1;

    }
}




void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{


         int res =internet_test();
             if (res == 1){
                   ui->checkBox->setChecked(true);
             }

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~MainWindow();

private slots:
     void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
     MainWindow w;
     w.show();

     return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>70</y>
      <width>83</width>
      <height>25</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>100</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>90</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>CheckBox</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>400</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```